# Cardview is not working properly in Devices lower than Lollipop

Tags: android, android-cardview

This screen shot is taken in Marshmallow

[image]

This one is taken in jelly bean in this the image is not shown and in the menus the text is not visible

[image]

I have a layout with Cardview as the parent view.

It consists of images and text.
Now the layout works fine on devices with Android M and above but in lower versions (like Jellybean ) the images are not shown properly.They turn small and are not matching the card view fully

Here's my layout XML file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            android:elevation="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/home_news_image"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/jesus" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/home_title_parish_news"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                        android:text="Christmas Celebration"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/home_short_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="hi this is to tell thlkdsa asdsag slk sg sdg sdgjs gsd gsg jglsgja gasjggjasg asgjasgj sgjasg g g"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/home_date_published"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:gravity="right|bottom"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="10/10/2010"
                        android:textSize="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the adapter where i initialize my layout and views

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<MenuModel> list;
    String img;


    public MenuAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<MenuModel> list) {
        mContext = c;
        this.list = list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null) {
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_grid_menu, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.home_grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.home_grid_image);
            textView.setText(list.get(i).getMenuName());
            imageView.setImageResource(list.get(i).getMenuImage());

        } else {
            grid = (View) view;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Also if I place a text under an image the text is not visible.

Please suggest me how to go about it.

I hope now i will get some solution

Comment: attach both images.

Comment: try wrapping cardview in framelayout (add between linear and cardview).

Comment: Where is your code, that initializes layout?

Comment: @ DeKaNszn I have added the adapter class where i initialize my views in the code part please see the question on top

Answer (score 2):

First you need to read the file from the assets folder in android here is the example how to read html file from assets folder

```
InoutInputStream is = getAssets().open("yourfile.html");
int size = is.available();

byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String str = new String(buffer);
```

You have the html file in the String now your need to get text from the html file using HTML.fromhtml.

```
String htmltext=Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(str).toString())
```

If you want to share the html text then you can share the text using android intent

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing html Text");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, htmltext);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Select"));
```

Comment: This question is not about opening html

Comment: i thinks this is irrelevant to my question @Muhammad 

Please read my question 

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

card views works properly starting lollipop, they have backward support but rendering is usually not the same.

For the specific issue please attach images of both screen